# What is difference between application server and backend server

Tags: server

I'm new in IT operations, and I want to ask what is the difference between application server and backend server?

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs to serverfault or superuser. However after a [quick search](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-web-server-and-a-backend-server) I have found the following information:

> A backend server is generally an application server that software on the web server can call on behalf of the end user to perform business logic. ... A backend server is any remote server managing data. A webserver is a specific type of backend server used for “internet” traffic.

Or in simple terms: Users interact with application servers. backend servers may or may not be interacted with by users. A common example where this is not the case would be a database server, where the application server interacts with it.